# What is the difference between clearRect and reset method in HTML5 Canvas

Tags: canvas

I have been working on a feature that implements dragging and connecting bunch of rectangles in native Canvas API in React. I have been using `clearRect` method at the start of the `draw()` function to clear previous area and paint another one. But on Google Developers channel I have found `contenxt.reset()` method.

What is the difference between these two methods and which one should I use?

Comment: [`clearRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/clearRect) just clears the pixels. [`reset()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/reset) does a lot more: _Resetting clears the backing buffer, drawing state stack, any defined paths, and styles. This includes the current transformation matrix, compositing properties, clipping region, dash list, line styles, text styles, shadows, image smoothing, filters, and so on._

Comment: Thanks! I guess ````clearRect()```` is a better option for just clearing the canvas for the next repaint without the need to reset everything!